# Acceder al elemento de un JSON en C#

Tags: c#, json

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
{
"id": 0,
"levels": {
    "Nombre_ejemplo,0000": {
        "Nombre 1": {
            "parametro1": "10",
            "parametro2": "10"
        },
        "Nombre 2": {
            "Checkbox": true,
            "parametro1": "10",
            "parametro2": "10"
        },
        "Nombre 3": {
            "parametro1": "10",
            "parametro2": "10"
        }
    }      
}
}
```

¿Cómo podría acceder al **parametro1** de cualquiera de los elementos, conociendo su Nombre? Por ejemplo quiero conocer el valor de "parametro1" de "Nombre 1" de "Nombre_ejemplo,0000" de "levels"

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Trata de crear un modelo con respecto a tu Json, y con eso lo puedes convertir tu json en el objeto que creas, para que puedas iterar los valores que tengas dentro.

Answer (score -1):

Buscando en Google la frase "Acceder al elemento de un JSON en C#" y la frase "Access a JSON element C#" he encontrado muchos resultados.

Mira a ver si te sirve [este artículo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459155/how-to-access-json-object-in-c-sharp)

En él se indica lo siguiente:

> Primero descarga la librería `Newtonsoft`, luego haz el parse del objeto Json utilizando el JObject. Esto te permitirá acceder a las propiedades con bastante facilidad, algo como:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace testClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var myJsonString = "{report: {Id: \"aaakkj98898983\"}}";
            var jo = JObject.Parse(myJsonString);
            var id = jo["report"]["Id"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(id);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

También en [este otro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676746/parse-json-string-in-c-sharp) o [en este otro](https://zetcode.com/csharp/json/) se describen métodos similares, pero para lo básico ya lo deberías tener en esta respuesta.

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Comment: Lo he corregido y ampliado. Muchas gracias por el aviso ;)